# normal maps in ursina

Tags: python, python-3.x, normals, ursina

I wanted to if there is a way to add a normal map or a displacement map onto an Entity in Ursina Engine. I have looked for it in the cheat sheet and have not found a way but still wanted to ask if there is a way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am looking for that too. I think you will need to create a shader to do that